# Using a filter to add a cookie to the users session

Tags: java, cookies, response, servlet-filters

**Update: The issue is with the setting used for the MaxAge.  Setting it to zero will cause the cookie to be deleted, hence it was shown in the response header but was then deleted and did not show in the request.  Setting it to -1 so that it will not be stored persistently**

I am doing some work on a filter in which I want it to set a cookie to indicate that the user qualifies to take a survey and that the next time he comes back to the site a survey popup window will be displayed.

I am not seeing any errors in the logs but the cookie never gets set.

Can a filter be used this way to add a cookie?  Is there where a HttpServletResponseWrapper comes into play?

The thought here is that when the user comes to the the site there is a check to see if the cookie is present.  If it is not then a cookie is created and added to the response.  As the user navigates the site, the cookie check method is called to make sure that the hit counter is not increased for that given user.

The cookie check method never sees the cookie.  Using web developer plugin for firefox, the cookie in question is not present.

Below is the filter class with the relevant methods.

```
public class HitCounterFilter extends TemplateFilter {
    public void doMainProcessing(ServletRequest pRequest, ServletResponse pResponse, FilterChain pChain) {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) pRequest;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) pResponse;

        // prevent thread interference and memory consistency errors
        synchronized (lock) {
            int hitCounter = this.readFile(localFile);

            // if user has not been counted
            if (!this.checkForCookie(httpRequest, "gtgo_visitor")) {
                this.writeFile(localFile, ++hitCounter);
                this.createCookie(httpRequest, httpResponse, String.valueOf(hitCounter), "gtgo_visitor");
            }
        }
    }

    private void createCookie(HttpServletRequest pHttpRequest, HttpServletResponse pHttpResponse, String pCookieValue, String pCookieName) {
        try {
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie(pCookieName, pCookieValue);
            URL url = new URL(pHttpRequest.getRequestURL().toString());
            cookie.setDomain(url.getHost());
            cookie.setPath(this.getCookiePath(pHttpRequest));
            cookie.setComment("user is not eligible to take the survey this time");
            cookie.setMaxAge(0);

            pHttpResponse.addCookie(cookie);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private boolean checkForCookie(HttpServletRequest pHttpRequest, String pCookieName) {
        for (Cookie cookie : pHttpRequest.getCookies()) {
            if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(cookie.getName(), pCookieName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is too much code to curb. I'm pretty certain that over 90% of the code is irrelevant to the concrete problem. Please come up with the smallest possible but self-containing code snippet which still reproduces your problem. You have by the way not told how you concluded that the cookie is not set. Is it missing in the response header? Or is it missing in the request header of the subsequent requests?

Comment: Have made the edits - hopefully it is clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the setting used for the MaxAge. Setting it to zero will cause the cookie to be deleted, hence it was shown in the response header but was then deleted and did not show in the request. Setting it to -1 so that it will not be stored persistently - it will be present as long as the session is active (removed once the session is closed)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with the SCAM project before, but it looks like that is what you're using.  I'm not sure if the super class's implementation of doFilter calls your implementation's doMainProcessing method before calling the FilterChain's doFilter method or not.

Because the framework passes the FilterChain into your doMainProcessing method, it is likely that it expects that your implementation will call pChain.doFilter(pRequest, pResponse, pChain).

I might be wrong about this, but if the filter chain is abandoned, its possible that the headers written to the ServletResponse object, which include the cookie you have attached, will not be returned to the client.

In any case, unless you are specifically blocking access to the requested resource, its wise to propagate the request using the FilterChain.

Comment: When you said, "Using web developer plugin for firefox, the cookie in question is not present." Did you mean that you were examining subsequent requests or the response headers from the request that should have set it?

Comment: Using the same plugin for firfox, I selected to view response header and I see the following: Set-Cookie: gtgo_visitor=30; Domain=localhost; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/keurig  So this does indeed look as if the cookie is being set in the response.  So now the question is how do I access it - it does not appear in the HttpServletRequest#getCookies

Comment: Ah, I wish I would have seen your response before updating my answer.  The cookie is being set correctly.  So the issue is that it is incrementing the counter with each hit.  Cookies will only be supplied on requests to URLs which are at least as specific as the path they are set with.  If you want a single cookie for your entire host, then simply set the path to /.  But the first thing I would do is perform some debugging on the loop through request.getCookies() just to see what IS there.  This is likely an issue with the PATH declaration.

Comment: Using the Developer Tools from Chrome, I can see that the cookie is in the response but is not in the request regardless of pages that I am navigating to.  Not sure if it matters, I am using Spring MVC.

Comment: The issue is your cookie expires in 1970 ;)